# verb form(past participle, present participle)

Tags: word-usage, participles

From The Analysis of Mind by Bertrand Russell:

> The traditional conception of cause and effect is one which modern
>   science shows to be fundamentally erroneous, and **requiring** to be
>   replaced by a quite different notion, that of LAWS OF CHANGE.

I don't understand why *requiring* was used. I think it is incorrect, and *required* or *requiring* without the preceding *and* is grammatically correct. If I am wrong, please, enlighten me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I agree, the sentence is grammatically incorrect and the article is not needed as follows:

> The traditional conception of cause and effect is one which modern
>   science shows to be fundamentally erroneous, **requiring/required** to
>   be replaced by a quite different notion, that of LAWS OF CHANGE.

Comment: Thank you very much. But in case of "required", isn't the coordinator "and" needed?

Comment: Sorry, "and" is not needed. I was a little bit confused.